# Visa application for a multidestination trip

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, applications

I am an Indian citizen and I have planned a multidestination trip INDIA—-> Manila (4days)—-> Japan(10days)—-> Bangkok 3days—> India

My question is which country visa should I first apply for? Thank you!!!

Comment: It’s usual to apply in reverse order, that is first of all apply to the last jurisdiction on your itinerary for which you require a visa, then work backwards towards the first.

Comment: Japan visa holders can enter Philippines without a visa

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a comment, it is usual to apply in reverse order. It may not matter, but if it does, that is likely to be the best order.

The visa-issuing authority for country X rarely cares much about your plans for getting to country X. If those plans do not work, you are not their problem. They are much more like to care, when issuing a tourist or other short-stay visa, whether you have a feasible plan for leaving country X, and going somewhere else.

If you apply in reverse order you will have any visas you need to support your plans for leaving country X before applying for a country X visa.